# SELECT avg FROM SELECT avg

Tags: sql, oracle

I just dont kow how to make it work, how can i select the avg from the other select

```
select avg(avg(valoare)) from (select avg(valoare) from note 
where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS)
```

I've Also tried

```
  select avg(alias) from (select avg(valoare) as "alias" from note 
  where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS)
```

Comment: add a letter `a` at the end and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query is basically what you want. However once you start using double quotes for identifiers in SQL, these identifiers become case-sensitive: `"alias"` is a different name then `alias` (because `alias` is the same as `ALIAS`).

So you need to use the double quotes throughout the query:

```
select avg("alias") 
from (
  select avg(valoare) as "alias" 
  from note 
  where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS
)
```

Another option is to use a name that does not require quoting:

```
select avg(avg_valoare) 
from (
  select avg(valoare) as avg_valoare
  from note 
  where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS
)
```

---

Although not required by Oracle it is good coding style to give the derived table an alias as well.

```
select avg("alias") 
from (
  select avg(valoare) as "alias" 
  from note 
  where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS
) x --<<< here
```

Note that Oracle does *not* support the `AS` keyword for a table alias, so you can't use `) as x` for the derived table alias.

Comment: And because it's Oracle you could simply nest aggregates :-) `select avg(avg(valoare)) from note 
where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS`  (Of course I would never actually recommend this)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query.

```
select avg(alias) from 
      (select avg(valoare) as alias from note 
         where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS) X
```

OR

```
select avg(avg(valoare)) as alias from note 
    where nr_matricol=111 group by ID_CURS X
```